# Parameterize a JDBC SQL Query in SOAP UI from a Custom Property

Tags: sql, jdbc, soapui

To proceed with a Database validation, I am having a need of comparing a record in the DB along with a data which is dynamically generated in the previous REST response, using `SoapUI`.

I have already captured the property value using a `Property Transfer` step and stored the required value in a custom property in Test-Case successfully i.e., using property expansion, say `${TestCase#customerId}`

My intention is to use that particular value stored in the custom properties to query the result I am expecting, in the `JDBC Request` test step.

The query which I have drafted with the parameter is as below :

```
Select * 
From ABC.SEC_CUST
Where ABC.SEC_CUST.CUSTOMER_ID =  ${TestCase#customerId}
```

The response I receive after executing is as below.

> Error getting response; java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException : ORA-00911: Invalid character.

But, when I run the query without the parameterized value it executes perfectly. Where, I tend the conclusion as there is a syntax issue in the way I have mentioned the parameter in the query.

But, I am unable to find the correct way to mention the parameter in the query in SoapUI.

Can anyone with experience in SoapUI, please assist me on this?

Comment: Please check the solution and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: hirosht, have you got chance to try the answer?

Comment: @Rao, Yes your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not working because of the use of property expansion which is only known to `SoapUI`, but not for the `SQL query`.

In order to get it work for the same, you need to *define the variables* in the top for all the parameters that are going to be used in the *sql query*.

Here the screen shot which explains how to use the same:

[image]

Comment: Old answer, I know. But still - how to get it as numeric? Using PostgreSQL when I just take it from the properties in the test case it says its varchar in the query while it's just a number.

Comment: @Matthiasdirickx Simply use the function provided by your database system inside the SQL query. For Oracle it would be this: TO_NUMBER(:customerid)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a '#'

```
Select * 
From ABC.SEC_CUST
Where ABC.SEC_CUST.CUSTOMER_ID =  ${#TestCase#customerId}
```

Comment: Also, if customer_id is not a numeric value in your database (poor design happens), you have to add simple quotes : Where ABC.SEC_CUST.CUSTOMER_ID =  '${#TestCase#customerId}'

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select * From ABC.SEC_CUST
Where ABC.SEC_CUST.CUSTOMER_ID = :customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by others you simply forgot a '#' in the parameter name.

To avoid such mistakes use the built-in context menu of the "SQL Query" text field. It has a menu entry called "Get Data..." which lets you insert all known properties into the SQL statement.